# Displaying JSON on HTML returned from Web Api Controller

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-web-api

I have created the Web Api project with MVC.I want to display the JSON result in HTML page.
How should i do that?
URL:

```
http://localhost:58379/api/ccpayment/GetEligibility?userid=3830&type=json
```

and the data i am getting is in the following format

```
{"DailyAllowance":10000.00,"AmountUsedForTheDay":0.00,"CDF":3.0000,"UserEligibleForCC":"EligibleButBanned"}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getYourData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/yourAPI_URL",
        data: JSON.stringify({ yourPostDataIfAny }),
        type: "Post",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    }).then(function (data) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(data);

        //your input field on page
        txtAllowance.value = response.DailyAllowance;
    });
}
```